# How can we compute restrictions from a character table?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, permutations, representation-theory, characters

I would like to how to, when given a character table, calculate the restriction.

$Res_H^G : Rep(G) \rightarrow Rep(H)$.

For example:

> Let $G=S_4$ whose character table is given below (see picture), and $H=<(123)>$, the cyclic group generated by the cycle $(123)$. Compute the restrictions $Res_H^G\chi_i$ for $i=1, ..., 5$

[image: S4]

Can these be computed from character; I assume so since we are given the character table?

Comment: Yes, they are completely given by looking at the character table, as you just need to list their values on the conjugacy classes of the subgroup.

Comment: For operators like $\operatorname{Res}$ and $\operatorname{Rep}$ that don't have a command of their own, you can use e.g. `\operatorname{Res}` to get the right font.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Why are we able to do this?

Comment: We are able to do this because the restricted character really just is the restriction of the map to the subgroup.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft ok thank you for your help :) I just find representation theory is very un-intuitive to me

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can. As Tobias wrote in a comment, they follow directly by restricting the table to the columns $1$ and $(123)$ that represent the conjugacy classes that make up the normal subgroup. Denoting the three irreducible characters of $H$ by $X_k=\exp(2k\pi \mathrm i/3)$, you can use the restricted characters to find how the irreducible characters of $G$ decompose into irreducible characters of $H$:

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Res}^G_H\xi_1&=X_1\;,\\
\operatorname{Res}^G_H\xi_2&=X_1\;,\\
\operatorname{Res}^G_H\xi_3&=X_1+X_2+X_3\;,\\
\operatorname{Res}^G_H\xi_4&=X_1+X_2+X_3\;,\\
\operatorname{Res}^G_H\xi_5&=X_2+X_3\;.
\end{align}